# Hiding mode-line in speedbar buffer

Tags: hooks, mode-line, speedbar

I would like to hide the mode-line completely in a speedbar buffer. Calling `(setq mode-line-format nil)` in the buffer works temporarily, but I would like to make this setting permanent. Adding a hook using `(add-hook 'speedbar-mode-hook (lambda () (setq mode-line-format nil)))` has no effect. What is the correct way to achieve this?

I am using emacs 25.2.1 on macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(require 'speedbar)

(defun speedbar-set-mode-line-format ()
  (setq mode-line-format nil))
```